# How could I control amplify DataStore sync

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

1. I want to configure the syncing of data in a button click. Now it syncs all data when it online.
2. I have two models `Post` and `Comment`. When I am fetching all data from `Post`, it syncs `Comment`s data too. I want only `Post` data for a particular user, but it syncs `Comment` too.

How could I achieve this? Please help.

Please see the code

```
import { DataStore} from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
import { Post } from "../models";
import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core";
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

public async findAllPosts() {
    return await DataStore.query(Post);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DataStore is designed to sync all data for an app by default. It will try to keep the entire data set for the app accessible by the current user both in the cloud and locally (in IndexedDB by default).

You can change the default behavior and sync only a subset of the data using sync expressions when configuring Datastore. An example from the doc:

```
import { DataStore, syncExpression } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Post, Comment } from './models';

DataStore.configure({
  syncExpressions: [
    syncExpression(Post, () => {
      return post => post.rating('gt', 5);
    }),
    syncExpression(Comment, () => {
      return comment => comment.status('eq', 'active');
    }),
  ]
});
```

See the Datastore topic documentation for details on [Selectively syncing a subset of your data](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/js/#selectively-syncing-a-subset-of-your-data).